# Should java comparator classes be in a seperate file?

Tags: java, class, comparator

Currently I have a comparator class in the same file as one of my classes.

```
public class Tree {

    public static Comparator<Tree> TreeSize = new Comparator<Tree>() {
        public int compare(Tree t1, Tree t2)
        {
            etc...
        }
    }

}
```

Should the Comparator class be in its own file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you happen to have just one comparator, why not just impose a natural ordering by having the class implement `Comparable`? Then you can not only keep it at the class level, but you don't need the second class at all.

Answer (score 2):

(I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, since the code above is not legal. You can't declare such a thing at the top level. Are you trying to declare a second class? I'm assuming that.)

As a matter of style, I find it highly unconventional (though possible) to put more than one top-level declaration in one Java source file. I would certainly prefer a separate source file for your `Comparator`.

You can also make it a public, static member of the `Tree` class. This makes some style sense since it inherently goes with instances of `Tree`. But I myself still prefer separate top-level classes when possible.